# segues in storyboard work perfectly but the prepare for segue is not being called

Tags: iphone, ios

So I have a standard method that everyone uses in the prepare for segue.
When I think logically "prepare" means do this before the segue is called.
But I have set up 3 table cells that all have 1 segue to the `SecondViewController`.
When I test that it works perfectly no errors.

Now when I want to add to this app that when the user selects the first cell the label "labeltje" get another text value  this does not happen.
Of course this code is in my `TableViewController.m` file and not in the `DagenViewController`, which is my second controller.

What am I not seeing?
`Dagenviewcontroller` is imported etc. no issues there.
This is the prepareforsegue bit of code:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DagenViewController *secondVC = (DagenViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vrijdagSegue"])
    {
        NSString *vrijdag = @"vrijdag";
        secondVC.labeltje.text = vrijdag;
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"zaterdagSegue"])
    {
        NSString *zaterdag = @"zaterdag";
        secondVC.labeltje.text = zaterdag;
    }
    else {
        NSString *zondag = @"zondag";
        secondVC.labeltje.text = zondag;
    }
}
```

Or is there a way to put something in the `ViewDidLoad` method of my `SecondViewController` that checks which segue was used?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You said that you have only one segue than how u have three different  segue identifier? One segue have only one identifier.

Comment: And if you want to do this with one segue (which it should be) than you have to write condition based on selected row not on segue.identifier.

Comment: But I have set up 3 table cells that all have 1 segue to the SecondViewController. I think you misread :)
For me it is really necessary to have only 3 cells so I set everything up as I want it to. Therefore I don't use much of the table stuff itself.

Comment: You have three row in table but you have one segue. so you have only one segue identifier. How u find vrijdagSegue and zaterdagSegue? What that text mean?

Comment: I think you are really missing the point :p I have 3 cells all with 1 segue. Cell 1 = vrijdagSegue, cell 2 = zaterSegue and so on :p

Comment: No I am not missing any thing just do one thing and you will get. Write first statement in this method  as NSLog(@"%@", segue.identifier). You will get same value for all three row.

Comment: The log gives my the correct segue mate :)

Comment: e1985 Solution work for u?

Comment: I just have a new issue now, look at my comment on his post for the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this way:

DagenViewController.h file

```
@property (strong, strong) NSString *preText
```

DagenViewController.m file

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    self.labeltje.text = preText;
}
```

In Your Method

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DagenViewController *secondVC = (DagenViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vrijdagSegue"])
    {
        secondVC.preText = @"vrijdag";
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"zaterdagSegue"])
    {
         secondVC.preText = @"zaterdag";
    }
    else {
         secondVC.preText = @"zondag";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the best!
+ the best thing now is that I actually understand it :D
Thank you so much!

Comment: u r welcome...... But this is not best way. If your source and destination viewcontroller are same than should have one segue. Think what happen if you have more rows may be 10, 100 or 1000. So insted of giving condition on segue. identifier make condition on row value or make generic logic.

Answer (score 1):

When `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called you are accessing a label that is nil since the view controller's view was not yet loaded. Create a string property(that you will set in `prepareForSegue:sender:`) and then in your `DagenViewController` `viewDidLoad` method set the label's text from that string property.

Comment: I think this the answer I am looking for! I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this in the prepareforsegue:
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vrijdagSegue"])
    {
       dag = @"vrijdag";
       
    }
But the value dag is not passed on to DagenViewController, I imported everything correctly I think.